# Git commit of local branch to repo copies master files also

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a repo set up with just the master with files in it. On my local machine i created a directory within the folder thats linked to the master repo.

While working in the newly created directory i ran `git checkout -b new-branch` I then added some files, then ran the typical:

```
git add .
git commit -m 'new-branch'
git push
```

The push adds all the files from master including the new directory to the new branch.

I've tried various different push commands:

```
git push -u new-branch
git push -u origin new-branch
git push -u origin new-branch:new-branch
```

They all result the same; master files including new directory in the new branch.

Is it possible to just make the newly created directory into a branch by itself without the master files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might help to explain a bit more what you were trying to achieve - it seems like you may have a misunderstanding of what a branch is for, but it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 4):

Let's look at the lines you ran one by one and explain what they actually do:

```
git checkout -b new-branch
```

This is actually a shortcut for two commands: it first creates a branch called "new-branch", which starts out pointing at whatever you have checked out, and then it checks out (switches to) that branch. If you had "master" checked out when you ran it, "new-branch" initially points at the same commits as "master".

```
git add .
```

The "add" command adds files to git's "staging area"; effectively, it tells git which changes you want to be included in the next commit. The argument "." just means "the current directory", so this command says "include all changes in the current directory in the next commit".

```
git commit -m 'new-branch'
```

This creates a new commit, on the current branch - in this case, "new-branch", which you switched to above. The -m argument specifies the message you want to show in history for this commit, which would normally be something like "Added customer sign-up form", or "Fixed bug in sales report".

The commit contains a complete snapshot of the repository, including everything from the previous commit, and whatever changes you "staged" with "git add". When viewing the commit in future, you will generally see a comparison against the previous commit - that is, you'll see the *changes made* during this commit. But if you check out the commit, it contains the whole repository - a particular version of the application you're working on.

```
git push
```

This doesn't create anything, it just shares the new commit you made with a remote server somewhere. Trying different versions of "push" isn't going to make a difference to what is committed, that already happened in the previous commands.

> Is it possible to just make the newly created directory into a branch by itself without the master files?

If you want the new branch to be linked in history to master, but never contain any of the old code, you'll need to *delete* those files - imagine reading through the history as a series of changes; there needs to be a change somewhere to go from "the files are there" to "the files are not there". I'm not sure why you'd want to do that, though, and suspect there's some deeper misunderstanding of how to use version control effectively.

If you just want the new directory to be a completely separate project, you probably just want a completely new repository, rather than just a new branch.

Comment: My fault, i neglected to mention i ran git checkout -b new-branch in the new directory

Comment: @MaxxABillion It doesn't make any difference where you run the command, the branch is a branch of the repository - a set of parallel versions of the application you're working on.

Comment: I'm working on a feature thats separate from the program, e.g. building a pipeline, and pushing the code to aws. If the feature works, then i will add it to the main program. If it doesn't, i'm back to square one. So I guess this is sorta of a test branch, without the need of the original program.

Comment: @MaxxABiilion If it's eventually going to be part of the same directory, just put it there alongside the other files. If and when you come to merge it, git will notice that the changes on the branch are all adding new files, and add them without changing the rest of the program. There *are* ways to make two independent histories and then glue them together, but they're a lot of extra complication, so you'd need a good reason to bother. If you just want a throwaway prototype, you could just leave it in its own repository which you delete at the end.

Comment: @MaxxABillion you might want to read this post I've recently made: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ You have a very basic misconception about what a commit is. My article will fix that.